# LINQ Statement WHERE Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am returning a list.  This is contains the names of xml nodes that cannot be blank in my XML file.

```
List<Setting> settingList = SettingsGateway.GetBySettingTypeList("VerifyField");
```

I have a LINQ Statement. I am trying to return all transactions that have empty nodes. The list here is returning the nodes that CANNOT be empty.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

The following code is supposed to Bind the "transactions" to a DataGrid and display the Txn's that have empty nodes which are required.

```
var transactionList =
from transactions in root.Elements(XName.Get("Transactions")).Elements().AsEnumerable()
where transactions.Elements().Any
(
    el => 
    //String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value) &&
    //elementsThatCannotBeEmpty.Contains(el.Name)
    settingList.Any(
        name => String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element(name.SettingValue).Value)
    )
)
select new
{
    CustomerName = transactions.Element(XName.Get("CustomerName")).Value,
    ConfirmationNumber = transactions.Element(XName.Get("ConfirmationNumber")).Value
 };

 GridView.DataSource = transactionList;
 GridView.DataBind();
```

**XML File Example:**

```
<OnlineBanking>
  <Transactions>
    <Txn>
      <UserName>John Smith</UserName>
      <CustomerStreet>123 Main</CustomerStreet>
      <CustomerStreet2></CustomerStreet2>
      <CustomerCity>New York</CustomerCity>
      <CustomerState>NY</CustomerState>
      <CustomerZip>12345</CustomerZip>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>
</OnlineBanking>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you're not using `name` within your inner lambda expression. What does `Setting` look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "CANNOT be empty?"

Comment: In the XML, the node <CustomerStreet></CustomerStreet> cannot be empty.

Comment: Ah, okay, with that edit it makes a bit more sense...

Comment: Setting has `SettingID`, `SettingType`, `Settingvalue`.  I am returning all rows that have SettingType of "VerifyField" which are `CustomerStreet`,  `CustomerCity`, `CustomerState`, `CustomerZip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first problem: if the element is *missing*, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

I'd suggest creating a `List<string>` of the elements which can't be null, to make the query simple. Then:

```
var requiredElements = settingList.Select(x => x.SettingValue).ToList();

var transactionList = root
      .Elements("Transactions")
      .Elements("Txn")
      .Where(x => requiredElements
                    .Any(name => string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) x.Element(name)));
```

I *think* that should be okay, and slightly simpler than your original code... but to be honest, your original code looks like it should have worked anyway. What did it actually do? You haven't been very clear about the *actual* results versus the expected ones...

Comment: I updated my code with MORE information.  I added more of my actual code to show you how I am selecting the nodes and binding them to a datagrid.  I hope this helps you, help me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var transactionList =
     root
    .Elements(XName.Get("Transactions")) //Get <Transaction> elements
    .Elements() //Get <Txn> elements
    .Where(txn => txn.Elements().Any(e => e.Value == String.Empty))  //Filter <Txn> Elements if it have any element like this: <CustomerStreet2></CustomerStreet2>
    .Select(x => new {
        PropertyX = x.Element(XName.Get("UserName")),
        PropertyY = x.Element(XName.Get("CustomerStreet")),
                    ...
    });
```

Works with:

```
<OnlineBanking>
  <Transactions>
    <Txn> <!-- This one matches! -->
      <UserName>John Smith</UserName>
      <CustomerStreet>123 Main</CustomerStreet>
      <CustomerStreet2></CustomerStreet2> 
      <CustomerCity>New York</CustomerCity>
      <CustomerState>NY</CustomerState>
      <CustomerZip>12345</CustomerZip>
    </Txn>
    <Txn> <!-- This one doesn't match! -->
      <UserName>John Smith</UserName>
      <CustomerStreet>123 Main</CustomerStreet>
      <CustomerStreet2>ASDASD</CustomerStreet2>
      <CustomerCity>New York</CustomerCity>
      <CustomerState>NY</CustomerState>
      <CustomerZip>12345</CustomerZip>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>
</OnlineBanking>
```

Comment: How can I add the "Select" in there similar to how I added in my code above.  I am binding the transactionList to a DataView and have two columns of `ConfirmationNumber` and `CustomerName`

Comment: Your code is returning all Txn's that are in the XML file, when it should not be.

Comment: Are you certain? I tried it with a 2 <Txn> sample and worked successfully.

Comment: I got it working with @Jon's example above.  Your code did not have the `var requiredElements = settingList.Select(x => x.SettingValue).ToList();` in it.